# Block doesn't execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am caching downloading and images in this way, but my problem is this `queryDiskCacheForDisk` block doesn't execute.

```
-(void)checkCache :(NSArray *)imgUrl
{
    float circleWidth=0.0;
    if (dm.screenWidth==320) {
        circleWidth=53.0;
    }

    else if(dm.screenWidth>320)
    {
        circleWidth=65.0;
    }
    CGRect circleFrame=CGRectMake(0, 0, circleWidth, circleWidth);
    __block UIImage *savedImage=[com circularScaleAndCropImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFound"] frame:circleFrame];
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"TEAM_PROFILES"];
    [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:0] done:^(UIImage *image,SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        // image is not nil if image was found

        if (image) {
            savedImage=[com circularScaleAndCropImage:image frame:circleFrame];

            NSLog(@"----image Cached------");
        }
        else
        {
            //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getImageNew:) withObject:nil];
            savedImage=[self getImageNew:imgUrl];
            [imageCache storeImage:savedImage forKey:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }];

    [arrayImages addObject:savedImage];
    [arrayTeamMemeberNames addObject:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:1]];
    [arrayEmpCodes addObject:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:2]];
    [arrEmpFullName addObject:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:3]];
    [arrEmpNumbers addObject:[imgUrl objectAtIndex:4]];
    if([arrayImages count]==[arrayTeamMembersUnfilter count])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"imagesFilledContact" object:nil];
        NSLog(@"------POST NOTIFICATION-----");

    }
}
```

It always added the default image I assigned at the begining. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In you block, I didn't see any `add` operation.

Do you know your block is the last part to run?